# Ok to use adapter pattern on concrete classes?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have two similar concrete classes that are provided by two different third parties (I cannot modify them).

Is it ok if I use the classic GoF adapter pattern but instead have my adapter extend the concrete target class? Or is this bad?

Example:

```
public class A {
   public void doSomething() {
      // some code
   }
}

public class B {
   public void similarDoSomethingMethod() {
      // some code
   }
}


public class BAdapter extends A {
   private B b;

   public BAdapter(B b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
   @Overrides
   public void doSomething() {
      b.similarDoSomethingMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: **Is a** `BAdapter` an `A`? If so, then this might be reasonable. Also, are you sure that by not calling `super.doSomething()`, you are not breaking invariants of `A` (keep in mind that implementors don't always use `final` and/or document side-effects when they really should have)? This does seem like a bit of a code smell but it's impossible to give more advice without more information (For example, *why* do you need this adapter? Can you give a more concrete example?)

Comment: I forgot to in original post  that the two classes come from two different third parties. I receive input from a third party using class A that needs to be posted to the other third party using class B. So I receive an instance of class A but I need to turn it into an instance of class B so that I can send it to the other third party. That's why I need the adapter. Hopes that makes sense.

Comment: My gut reaction is no. An adapter is used to provide your own interface to something. By extending the class, you're opening up calls to the actual object. I think using a `has-a` relationship is a better idea.

Comment: @dalexander06 What you're really trying to do is create some sort of bridge from an `A` to a `B`; there isn't really a "pattern" for that per-se, but your logic for doing this should be in your higher level control logic somewhere. Again, though, can't give solid advice without a concrete example (e.g. are you polling `A`? Does the `B` API provide some sort of interface you can implement? Is `B` pulling data or are you really posting data? Etc.) There is not enough information here to give you a correct answer.

Comment: sdasdadas - I can't use interfaces because I cannot change the two classes due to them being third party classes

Comment: That said, you may *have* to do it this way, if `A` does not implement some interface - it's possible that it is a design flaw in `A`'s library that you have to workaround, and it's OK as long as you document why you are doing it and *as long as you are 100% sure there is no other way*. Every once in a while it's OK to break the rules in special circumstances if it's the only way to get the job done, but you need to be aware of how and why you are breaking the rules, you need to justify it, and you need to document the rationale. And again, heed what I said about invariants / side-effects.

Comment: @JasonC there are no interfaces being provided by either class. When I say "posted", I mean that there is a third party component that has a method which accepts B as an argument. I need to use that method but since I only have A, I need to turn it into a B. The two classes A and B are basically the same but the come from two different third parties.

Comment: @dalexander06 (I think you mixed up your A's and B's in your comment, but anyways...) As long as you can do that without breaking any invariants or internal logic of the class you are extending, you *might* be OK. You probably want to take a look at the source for the B library if it is available, to see what assumptions are made (both in B's implementation and in the library methods that use your B parameter). The real question isn't so much the abstract "is it OK to use this pattern this way", it's the concrete "will this actually work given the real implementation of these two classes"?

Comment: thanks @JasonC I am leaning towards doing it this way. My only other option is using a static adapter class that takes in an instance of Class B and return an instance of Class A

Comment: @dalexander06 I would certainly think about the static bridge alternative if possible; the more you can avoid messing with the internals of A and B, the better (especially consider if the third-parties change internal implementation details of A and B later). Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapter provides client classes a [protected variation](http://martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/protectedVariation.pdf) among the adaptees, if you apply it as described:

[image: Adapter pattern applied]

This means that if the concrete third-party classes evolve, you have some protection to the client.

If you choose to extend A (i.e., making A's interface be the one Client uses), if A (the third-party class you don't control) changes, your client will be broken.

Also, if you want to support a new third-party extension, how do you add it with your design?

Note that if A changes in the "clean" application of Adapter (above), only the ServiceAdapterA will break. Also, if you add new third-party implementations, you only need to create a new adapter and make the adapted service method work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that extension is a bad idea, in this case. Imagine you're implementing an adapter around the following third party class:

```
class Person {

    public void walk () { ... }

}
```

If you use extension, you might write:

```
class PersonAdapter extends Person {

}
```

and you make a call like `person.walk()`. Awesome, right?

But what happens when you want to hide walk? You have to deprecate it, or override it - both ugly solutions.

It's better to wrap the class and then only provide an interface to the functions you need.

Comment: Without more concrete information from the OP, the best we can do is conjecture which runs the risk of being misleading.